# How to create a Sharepoint list that can be used by both an Access desktop application and an Access web app

Tags: list, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

A SharePoint **list** that can be edited by both MS Access desktop and MS Access web apps (Access 2013).

I want a SharePoint list that works offline and then syncs when the network is working.

Sorry, I have tried several things but getting nowhere. I am new to using SharePoint, but have spent years creating databases/software.

Things I have tried, and failed:

- creating tables offline then uploading as a linked SharePoint list. It uploads but then the web app only has **read access**.
- creating a web app, adding a list. But then the desktop application is unable to see the table.
- Creating an Access 2013 desktop application. Create a linked SharePoint list from the application. But the web app only has read access.

Edit: It says 'Read only' when I link a SharePoint list to a web app. i.e when I use Access 2013 to create a web app, at the point when I link the SharePoint list, it only gives me the option of a read only style link.

Comment: Which version of sharepoint are you using?

Comment: The Sharepoint is Office 365 - MS hosted. (I assume you mean MS hosted sharepoint vs a local server, or is there another kind?)

Comment: how many users (approx.) are connecting to this app?

Comment: Instead of trying to use different Models in a MVC solution, try moving your data connection to the controller. Both access and Web App should be able to use web services to make the calls. Build and deploy the list as your model, them use SharePoint Web Services as your view and use your app and access as your controller. Instead of using the built-in SP interface of Access, switch to use web services as a consumer and you will get there. If you want a demo, I will need some specific info about the composition of your data and versions of your apps.

Comment: @jpollar About 5-25 users. At the moment there is not much point for local hosting of share point. But longer term it could be an option.

Comment: @ghangas "web services as a consumer", have you a link or 2? .... Re:Data composition - 4 tables plus about 30 lookups. Plus photos done as attachements. Simple relationships between tables. Everything is latest production version (Access 2013 and MS hosted Share point)....  re:MVP. I am using an Access database. Are you suggesting switching to .net/ASP pages?

Comment: Thanks for the info, that will help a lot. re:MVP I am not suggesting you use any particular language, I am suggesting that you build your interface at the CSOM/JSOM level for the MS Access connection. If you can't do it with the Web App you shouldn't do it with Access. This is not a general principle, but the way to accomplish your specific project goals. One way to have the interface work from both Access and Web App is to architect the solution with the limit of the commonality of the 2 clients.

Comment: @ghangas When I say web app, I mean a MS Access Web App. I.e. a web app created using MS Access. (I will edit the question to make this clear)

Comment: Happy to award a bounty to an answer to this.

Comment: Look at the List Settings. In List Settings and Advanced settings you can specify that the list should be "Read only" under Create and Edit access. Is this the case? Can you change this?

Comment: @BOGLab Under "Create and Edit access:". The item "Create and edit all items" is selected.  .... Maybe it will help, but last time I tried this, the web app only had read access.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list in SP you could use the function to open list with Access[image: Open With Access on the SP List Ribbon]

When you do this it will ask you if you want to save your new access file to the SP server (answer yes and you have your linked Access file). This could be opened by access web services or access client. You could use that file to build all your forms in. This could be a workable solution if you want to link permanently to one list.

I think that there are some decent syncing options already built in to this solution. However, I am not entirely certain that this would fly in o365 and what all you want in your DB.

Comment: Your image with the "Open with Access" button. What tool is it, is it desktop or web based?

Comment: That was lighting up because it recognized my desktop one. However, one you open it using the desktop version, then you save the .accdb file to SharePoint and you will have the connected DB published to SP able to run in access services and desktop.